# PostGIS: How to dissolve vector data

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, vector, dissolve, simplify

I have a few scenarios where I need to dissolve vector data, and I'm wondering how to do this using PostGIS. What would the queries look like to perform these operations?

Below I'll describe the different cases through some simple examples.

The actual data I'm working with is considerably more massive and complex than these examples, in reality I'm working with data from OpenStreetMap (road networks, landuse polygons et.c.). PostGIS seems to be the foremost alternative for handling heavy data.

#### Segmented lines

Lines are split up into segments similarly to what is shown in the two images. The first line ("A-D") consists of three segments and has been split at B and C. I want to dissolve these three individual lines to get a line consisting of the vertices A,D. (vertices B,C are entirely redundant)

The second line isn't very different. It has been split at E and F into three smaller lines.

[image: line1]

[image: line2]

#### Dissolve polygons

The second issue concerns dissolving polygon data.  The geometries can either overlap or be within each other, touch (shared vertices) or *nearly* touch with some tiny distance separating the polygons.

For all of these cases I want to dissolve the polygons into larger geometries. I guess the last case where the polygons nearly touch is a bit special as the small space in between should be "filled out".

[image: poly1]

[image: poly2]

#### Final note

In the above cases the dissolving is solely based on spatial relationships. Non-geometric attributes aren't relevant.

As stated earlier the actual data I'm working with is pretty massive, and the base queries will likely have to be tweaked and optimized for handling very complex geometries.

If anyone would like to get the data shown in the examples it can be downloaded [here](http://pastebin.com/3HAwYpwj) as GeoJSON.

Answer (score 1):

If all your overlaps/touchings were in pairs, it would be a simple self-join, which would be ideal for efficiency.

The brute force answer is just something like:

```
CREATE TABLE merged AS
SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Union(geom)).geom AS geom
FROM mytable;
```

That'll take all the geometries into memory, throw them into a topology and extract the largest merged objects as a single geometry collection, then dump each element of the collection out into its own row.

For sufficiently large inputs, it could be terribly slow.

The trouble is, to do a more subtle merge operation you have to know *a priori* which groups of objects to merge. There's an `ST_ClusterIntersecting` function in PostGIS 2.2 what gets you some of the way there, but it's still an in-memory algorithm, so it might not be ideal.

Comment: why don't you use WHERE ST_Intersects() or something similar with a self-join? Could you please elaborate? I thought it would work for more than pairs as well... If not, how about making an array out of it and send it to ST_Union()?

Comment: WHERE ST_Intersects() will find each pair separately, so you'll end up with a much of unioned pairs, but not a single unioned area in the case where multiple objects overlap. You'll also end up with duplication. Have three overlapping objects? You'll get back three pairs in the simple self-join case.

Comment: Doing WHERE ST_Intersects with ST_Union gives an expected result from http://postimg.org/image/f6c7po9f3/ - a single polygon based on those 3. Am I missing something?

Comment: Show the actual SQL. You're probably multiplexing your data w/ the join then aggregating it all into one bucket in the end anyways unless there's some GROUP BY I'm not understanding in there.

Comment: SELECT ST_Intersection(a.wkb_geometry, b.wkb_geometry)
FROM test.test a, test.test b
WHERE ST_Intersects(a.wkb_geometry, b.wkb_geometry);

OK... long hours today, used intersection instead of union :-/

Comment: Hello Paul, your initial query successfully dissolved most of the polygons, but naturally didn't dissolve the _nearly_ _touching_ ones. What are your thoughts on handling that last case? Could one of the Snap functions of PostGIS be the key, or perhaps by buffering the geometries by some tiny amount? ... When I tested the query on the line data no dissolving was performed, I still had all the segments left and they hadn't been dissolved into larger lines. Should it have worked?

Comment: ... Finally I would just like to point out that there seems to be a parentheses mismatch in your query, it's missing a third ')'. It should be `(ST_Dump(ST_Union(geom))).geom`

Comment: Yes, a small buffer should to it for the polygons. The lines are probably not unioning for the same reason the polygons aren't: not exactly the same. Try an ST_Snap on them maybe?

Comment: @PaulRamsey adding an ST_Buffer operation resulted in that the _nearly_ _touching_ polygons dissolved too, which is good. The query that I ran was thusly `ST_Dump(ST_Union(ST_Buffer(geom,0.001))).geom`. (The value 0.001 creates a rather large buffer in this context and could be decreased somewhat.)

Comment: @PaulRamsey Regarding the line geometries I've encountered a few issues. The points appear to be _exactly_ _the_ _same_, so simply doing an ST_Union _should_ work, but it doesn't. Here is some output from what I see in PostGIS: http://pastebin.com/evHkKeRM I would appreciate it if you could test and see what behavior you're getting.

Comment: @PaulRamsey I have tried to dissolve the line geometries by running `select (ST_Dump(ST_Union(ST_Snap(a.geometry, b.geometry, 0.00001)))).geom as geometry from testline1 a, testline1 b where ST_Dwithin(a.geometry, b.geometry, 0.0001)` (testline1 being the table holding the lines from my example.)